# Copy tables from 1 Oracle to another Oracle instance

Tags: oracle

I have 2 Oracle instance:

- Oracle 1
- Oracle 2

I have created a database link on Oracle 1 to connect with Oracle 2.

I need to copy tables from Oracle 1 to Oracle 2 from Oracle 1. Is it possible?

Please note I know about:

```
create tmp_table as select * from table@oracle_2
```

but this will create table in Oracle 1 and NOT Oracle 2.

Note: I need to do this from Oracle 1, because I have many Oracle instances and want to copy to those instances in an automated way without logging on to each Oracle.

Comment: You need to run that `create table` statement in the second instance and for that you need a DbLink _from_ Oracle2 _to_ Oracle1

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I don't want to go to second instance and run. I need a way to do it on Oracle_1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are more than a couple of tables you should try to do it using `expdp` with [NETWORK_LINK](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g#NetworkExportsImports)

Something like this:

```
expdp test/test@oracle1 tables=tmp_table,tmp_table2 network_link=oracle_2 directory=TEST_DIR dumpfile=tmp.dmp logfile=expdptmp.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Command

```
create tmp_table@oracle_2 as select * from table
```

would lead you to an error:

> `ORA-00901: invalid CREATE command`

So what you need to do, is **connect to `oracle_2`**, and run it using newly created ***`oracle_1`*** db link!

```
 create tmp_table as select * from table@oracle_1
```

Comment: Then you should create a procedure on `oracle_1` to do it when its called. Try by yourself, and if you can't, come back with *another* question (its free).

Answer (score 0):

Copy from `user1/pwd@DB1` to `user2/pwd@DB2`. And, create table using

```
SELECT * FROM tablename;
```